# How can i extract the first and last number from a string separated by semicolons?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string in cell A1

```
7;19;28;42;
```

I would like to extract the first and last numbers. I have used this to extract the first number successfully

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT($a1,FIND(";",$a1)-1)),$a1,LEFT($a1,FIND(";",$a1)-1))
```

I have used this to try and extract the last number

```
=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT($a1,FIND(";",$a1)+1)),$a1,RIGHT($a1,FIND(";",$a1)+1))
```

However the problem I am finding is that the last number often has the semicolon before and/or after it. Is there anyway just to extract the numbers?

Comment: is there always a `;` on the end of the numbers?

Comment: There is always one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter version of getting the first:

```
=LEFT($A1,FIND(";",$A1 & ";")-1)
```

To get the last:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID($A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(";" & $A1,";","}}}",LEN(";" & $A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(";" & $A1,";",""))-1)),LEN($A1)),";","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extract first number :

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(A1,ROW($1:$9)))
```

Extract last number :

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";"," ")),ROW($1:$9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solutions just for FBF `Friday-Brainstorm-Fun` :)

First number

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","t/s[1]")
```

Last number:

```
=--TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),";",REPT(" ",500)),100))
```

[image: Solutions]

Answer (score 0):

Just for my own amusement, one that gets the last number in all these cases:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";"," "))," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

[image]